# Unable to target element using protractor's binding locator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

```
<div class="apiRequestDisplay ng-scope">
    <pre class="ng-binding">GET</pre>
    <pre class="ng-binding">v1/securityprofiles/{securityProfileID}    </pre>
</div>
```

I need to target the text that says `v1/securityprofiles/{securityProfileID}`. I inspected the element on the webpage to obtain the HTML at the top. As you can see it doesn't show `ng-bind` = to anything it just shows it as part of a class.

I thought that was a little weird but I used inspect Angular Scope (firefox add-on) to verify the binding to be `docsEndpoint.Endpoint.HttpVerb` however when I put it into the protractor syntax:

```
var route1 = element(by.binding('docsEndpoint.Endpoint.UriTemplate'));

expect(route1).toBe('v1/securityprofiles/{securityProfileID}');
```

and run it nothing happens. What am I missing?

I know I can probably select it using CSS selectors and I probably will if I have to but I really want to know why it isn't working.

Comment: I think the way you used by.binding is wrong one.Can you please share the complete html for this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `expect` an element itself, get it's text via [`getText()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) and use `toEqual()`:

```
expect(route1.getText()).toEqual('v1/securityprofiles/{securityProfileID}');
```